# How to analytically evaluate $\cos(\pi/4+\text{atan}(2))$

Tags: trigonometry

This equals $\cos(\pi/4)\cos(\text{atan}(2))-\sin(\pi/4)\sin(\text{atan}(2))$.

I'm just not sure how to evaluate $\cos(\text{atan}(2))$

Answer (score 3):

You can think of $\arctan(2)$ as an angle whose tangent is $2$.

To visualize such an angle, draw a right triangle and mark an acute angle.  Then opposite the marked angle have a side (leg) of length $2$, and adjacent to the marked angle have a side (leg) of length $1$.

The marked angle now represents $\arctan(2)$.

You can then fill in the hypotenuse of the right triangle, and use your diagram to find the necessary values for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\sin(\arctan(2))=\frac{\tan(\arctan(2))}{\sec(\arctan(2))}=\frac2{\sqrt5}$ and $\cos(\arctan(2))=\frac1{\sec(\arctan(2))}=\frac1{\sqrt5}$

Recall that $\sec^2(\theta)=\tan^2(\theta)+1$

Answer (score 2):

Graphically, we may say $\theta$ is an angle in a right-angled triangle where the opposite side is 2 and the adjacent side is 1, so that $\arctan{\theta}=2$

As the Hypotenuse side=$\sqrt5$, we have $\cos{(\arctan2)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}$

[image]

Comment: Whenever I face problems like this I draw the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another explanation.  Let $\theta=\arctan 2$ so that $\tan\theta=2$.  Since, $\sec\theta=\sqrt{1+\tan^2}\theta$, we get that $\sec\theta=\sqrt5$; hence
$\cos\theta=\cos(\arctan2)=1/\sqrt5$.